Blue screen (BSOD) after updating to flutter 3.27
After updating my flutter sdk to 3.27.1, I can not run or debug my app on the android emulator. App runs on the web or a device. I have updated the emulator too but when I run the project, the windows faces blue screen error WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR.
Evering thing was working fine before updating flutter sdk.

That seems to be caused by faulty hardware or driver. Please try searching the internet for WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR instead.
